# Функция .scroll Jquery

Tags: jquery

При таком скрипте не срабатывает условие if, выполняется else.
В чем может быть ошибка?

```
    <script>
    var top1= $('#hero li:nth-child(1)').offset();
    var top2= $('#hero li:nth-child(2)').offset();
    var top3= $('#hero li:nth-child(3)').offset();
    var top0= $("#hero_wrap").scrollLeft();

    $("#hero_wrap").scroll(function()
    {
    if ($top2.left = $top0)
    {$("#korabl").animate({"background-position": "85% 85%"}, 1200 );}
    else
    {$("#korabl").animate({"background-position": "50% 85%"}, 1200 );} 
 });
</script>

<style>
#hero_wrap {position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0; overflow:hidden; }
#hero {width: высчитывается от ширины экрана*кол-во ли;}
#hero li {width:высчитывается от ширины экрана; float:left;}
</style>

<div id="hero_wrap">
<ul id="hero">
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
<li> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**upd.**
поправил код. проблема в том что srollLeft k #hero_wrap возвращает ноль и offset.left для li тоже возвращает 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это что? Вы сравнивать собираетесь или присваивать значение?

```
if ($top2.left = $top0)
```

Может все-таки так?:

```
if ($top2.left == $top0)
```

Как вы без отладчика работаете - останется загадкой ))

Comment: спасибо за поправку. у меня совсем не очень с синтаксисом.
но проблема все равно в том что scrollLeft возвращает ноль :)

Comment: Сделайте пример на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Разобрался. Я объявлял переменные раньше чем происходило событие, поэтому возвращался 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Что у Вас делает эта строка `$("#hero").scrollLeft()>$li2`?

Comment: извините, вползло условие с другого куска кода.
опытным путем выяснил, что проблема в том что Scrollleft и offset.left возвращает 0.
сейчас делаю так:
var $top2= $('#hero li:nth-child(2)').offset();
var $top0= $("#hero_wrap").scrollLeft()

if ($top2.left = $top0)  {
  $("#korabl").animate({"background-position": "85% 85%"}, 1200 );
  }